# return file not exist when use Action Result as returen type in mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have action link

```
    @Html.ActionLink(@Resources.Resource_ar.Download, "DownloadFile", new { Communicationid = item.Communicationid }, new { @class = "btn btn-success btn_Download" })
```

call action to download file

```
   public ActionResult DownloadFile(string Communicationid)
    {


        string pathString = Settings.getSettingValue("FolderForSaveCommunicationsAttachments");
        //string FullPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/UploadedAttachment/"), FileName);
        string FullPath = Path.Combine(pathString, Communicationid);


        Communications ObjCommunication = new Communications(int.Parse(Communicationid));
        string FileName = ObjCommunication.s_FileName;

        //return File(FullPath, "text/docx");

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(FullPath))
        {
            string contentType = string.Empty;

            if (FileName.Contains(".pdf"))
            {
                contentType = "application/pdf";
            }
            else if (FileName.Contains(".docx"))
            {
                contentType = "application/docx";
            }
            else if (FileName.Contains(".doc"))
            {
                contentType = "application/doc";
            }
            else if (FileName.Contains(".jpeg"))
            {
                contentType = "image/jpeg";
            }
            else if (FileName.Contains(".jpg"))
            {
                contentType = "image/jpg";
            }
            else if (FileName.Contains(".png"))
            {
                contentType = "image/png";
            }
            else if (FileName.Contains(".bmp"))
            {
                contentType = "image/bmp";
            }
            else if (FileName.Contains(".xlsx"))
            {
                contentType = "application/xlsx";
            }
            else if (FileName.Contains(".Exl"))
            {
                contentType = "application/Exl";
            }
            else if (FileName.Contains(".txt"))
            {
                contentType = "application/txt";
            }
            return File(FullPath, contentType, FileName);
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }

    }
```

the problem is that when the file exist it return the file and download it correctly but when the file not exist I want to show alert to user tell him the file not exist what should i return 
I try to return javascript("alert('file not exist')") put it gave me blank page with text i put which "alert('file not exist')"
any help with this problem
thanks in advance

Comment: You could use the ViewBag. Add a property like 'ErrorMessage' to it and show it inside your view if it exists.

Comment: You'd normally expect a HTTP server to return a `404 Not Found` if a file doesn't exist.

Comment: @phuzi I want to gave user readable alert not 404 error

Comment: @greenhoorn what should i return in my action

Comment: @Radwa, How about redirecting to an error page which, can also return a 404 status code.

Comment: @phuzi good idea thanks for your help

Comment: @Radwa As phuzi already said, you can either redirect to another page or return the page from which the request came from. Either way you have to display the error message.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
 if (System.IO.File.Exists(FullPath))
                { //....
                }
                else { return Content("Some error message"); }
```

But i'd rather return a 404 if that file isn't there.

Comment: this gave me  blank page with text i put